# Using fields from different universes in Business objects

Tags: business-objects, universe

I am trying to put a report from two different universes. is it possible to add fields from both universes into a single report?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a commonly used functionality. However there are rules on how to combine data sets (be it from the same or a different universe) and what you can do with them.

As this is a quite extensive topic, I suggest you have a look at the Web Intelligence (I'm assuming this is the application you're using, as you haven't specified it) manuals, corresponding to the version of BusinessObjects you're using. The manuals are available at [help.sap.com](http://help.sap.com).

You might also find the interactive tutorials available on [sap.com/LearnBI](http://www.sap.com/LearnBI) helpful.